# getfilesavename is not defualting to current directory

Tags: powerbuilder

getfilesavename is not defulting to current directory. Its opening previously saved path.
Is this a bug of getfilesavename. its working good through code but this problem is when i deployed the exe.

here is my code

```
string filename,filepath
changedirectory('C:\')
messagebox('hi',getcurrentdirectory())
IF getfilesavename("Save File",filepath,filename,"xls","Excel files,*.xls",getcurrentdirectory() ) =0 THEN return
ole_1.activate(offsite!)
ole_1.object.application.activeworkbook.saveas(filepath)
```

Comment: My understanding is that your expectation is how older versions of Windows deal with that API command when no directory is specified (as PB does), while newer versions retain an application-specific directory-last-used as a default. If you want control, you want to look at Roland's code.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example app that shows how to use the Windows API functions to get a filename. It gives you better control over it than the built in PB function.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_getfilename.html

Comment: it did not worked for me.after deploying exe its opening the previous saved path, rather opening my documents

Answer (score 0):

What my understanding is you are not getting the current directory to store your files, your code is right with a simple modification. Here is my solution. This will get you into the application working directory.

```
string ls_path, ls_file
int li_rc
ls_path =GetCurrentDirectory( )
li_rc = GetFileSaveName ( "Select File", ls_path, ls_file, "DOC", "All Files (*.*),*.*" , "C:\My Documents",  32770)
```

Regards

Pushparaj